# SOLR facet search by prefix with results highlighting

Tags: solr, facet

Can I search via facet by prefix with results highlighting?
For example I have 2 documents:
name = "document1" title = "Simple query"
name = "document2" title = "Simple queries"

can I searching documents with prefix "quer"? And can I highlight returned results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facet.prefix just limits the terms on which to facet to those starting with the given string prefix.

This does not effect or change the search results, it simply reduces the facet values returned to those beginning with the specified prefix.

Search results would be determined only by the queries and limited by facet or filter queries.

So you cannot search the documents using facet.prefix, not would the results be highlight by the parameter.